# Matrix Table with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML Structure

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<DATA>
    <GROESSE_ROW>
      <PLIEFERANT>10076002 alexa Wholesale</PLIEFERANT> 
      <DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE>2</DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE> 
      <ARTICLE_NO>1589206</ARTICLE_NO> 
      <ARTICLE_NAME>Herren-Armbanduhr</ARTICLE_NAME> 
      <COLOR_NO>0</COLOR_NO> 
      <COLOR>k.A.</COLOR> 
      <SIZING>0</SIZING> 
      <AMOUNT>20</AMOUNT> 
      <SUMAMOUNT>20</SUMAMOUNT> 
      <PRICE>5.59</PRICE> 
      <PRICE2>111.8</PRICE2> 
      <DISCOUNT>0</DISCOUNT> 
      <LIEFDATUM>20.07.11</LIEFDATUM> 
      <TRENNER>1589206--20.07.11</TRENNER> 
      </GROESSE_ROW>
    <GROESSE_ROW>
      <PLIEFERANT>10076002 alexa Wholesale</PLIEFERANT> 
      <DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE>2</DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE> 
      <ARTICLE_NO>1599843</ARTICLE_NO> 
      <ARTICLE_NAME>Damen-T-Shirt</ARTICLE_NAME> 
      <COLOR_NO>200</COLOR_NO> 
      <COLOR>Grün</COLOR> 
      <SIZING>36</SIZING> 
      <AMOUNT>9</AMOUNT> 
      <SUMAMOUNT>54</SUMAMOUNT> 
      <PRICE>3.45</PRICE> 
      <PRICE2>31.05</PRICE2> 
      <DISCOUNT>0</DISCOUNT> 
      <LIEFDATUM>20.07.11</LIEFDATUM> 
      <TRENNER>1599843--20.07.11</TRENNER> 
      </GROESSE_ROW>
    <GROESSE_ROW>
      <PLIEFERANT>10076002 alexa Wholesale</PLIEFERANT> 
      <DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE>2</DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE> 
      <ARTICLE_NO>1599843</ARTICLE_NO> 
      <ARTICLE_NAME>Damen-T-Shirt</ARTICLE_NAME> 
      <COLOR_NO>526</COLOR_NO> 
      <COLOR>Rosa</COLOR> 
      <SIZING>36</SIZING> 
      <AMOUNT>9</AMOUNT> 
      <SUMAMOUNT>54</SUMAMOUNT> 
      <PRICE>3.45</PRICE> 
      <PRICE2>31.05</PRICE2> 
      <DISCOUNT>0</DISCOUNT> 
      <LIEFDATUM>20.07.11</LIEFDATUM> 
      <TRENNER>1599843--20.07.11</TRENNER> 
      </GROESSE_ROW>
    <GROESSE_ROW>
      <PLIEFERANT>10076002 alexa Wholesale</PLIEFERANT> 
      <DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE>2</DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE> 
      <ARTICLE_NO>1599843</ARTICLE_NO> 
      <ARTICLE_NAME>Damen-T-Shirt</ARTICLE_NAME> 
      <COLOR_NO>526</COLOR_NO> 
      <COLOR>Rosa</COLOR> 
      <SIZING>38</SIZING> 
      <AMOUNT>9</AMOUNT> 
      <SUMAMOUNT>54</SUMAMOUNT> 
      <PRICE>3.45</PRICE> 
      <PRICE2>31.05</PRICE2> 
      <DISCOUNT>0</DISCOUNT> 
      <LIEFDATUM>20.07.11</LIEFDATUM> 
      <TRENNER>1599843--20.07.11</TRENNER> 
      </GROESSE_ROW>
    <GROESSE_ROW>
      <PLIEFERANT>10076002 alexa Wholesale</PLIEFERANT> 
      <DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE>2</DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE> 
      <ARTICLE_NO>1599843</ARTICLE_NO> 
      <ARTICLE_NAME>Damen-T-Shirt</ARTICLE_NAME> 
      <COLOR_NO>200</COLOR_NO> 
      <COLOR>Grün</COLOR> 
      <SIZING>38</SIZING> 
      <AMOUNT>9</AMOUNT> 
      <SUMAMOUNT>54</SUMAMOUNT> 
      <PRICE>3.45</PRICE> 
      <PRICE2>31.05</PRICE2> 
      <DISCOUNT>0</DISCOUNT> 
      <LIEFDATUM>20.07.11</LIEFDATUM> 
      <TRENNER>1599843--20.07.11</TRENNER> 
      </GROESSE_ROW>
    <GROESSE_ROW>
      <PLIEFERANT>10076002 alexa Wholesale</PLIEFERANT> 
      <DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE>2</DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE> 
      <ARTICLE_NO>1599843</ARTICLE_NO> 
      <ARTICLE_NAME>Damen-T-Shirt</ARTICLE_NAME> 
      <COLOR_NO>200</COLOR_NO> 
      <COLOR>Grün</COLOR> 
      <SIZING>40</SIZING> 
      <AMOUNT>9</AMOUNT> 
      <SUMAMOUNT>54</SUMAMOUNT> 
      <PRICE>3.45</PRICE> 
      <PRICE2>31.05</PRICE2> 
      <DISCOUNT>0</DISCOUNT> 
      <LIEFDATUM>20.07.11</LIEFDATUM> 
      <TRENNER>1599843--20.07.11</TRENNER> 
      </GROESSE_ROW>
    <GROESSE_ROW>
      <PLIEFERANT>10076002 alexa Wholesale</PLIEFERANT> 
      <DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE>2</DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE> 
      <ARTICLE_NO>1599843</ARTICLE_NO> 
      <ARTICLE_NAME>Damen-T-Shirt</ARTICLE_NAME> 
      <COLOR_NO>526</COLOR_NO> 
      <COLOR>Rosa</COLOR> 
      <SIZING>40</SIZING> 
      <AMOUNT>9</AMOUNT> 
      <SUMAMOUNT>54</SUMAMOUNT> 
      <PRICE>3.45</PRICE> 
      <PRICE2>31.05</PRICE2> 
      <DISCOUNT>0</DISCOUNT> 
      <LIEFDATUM>20.07.11</LIEFDATUM> 
      <TRENNER>1599843--20.07.11</TRENNER> 
      </GROESSE_ROW>
    <GROESSE_ROW>
      <PLIEFERANT>10076002 alexa Wholesale</PLIEFERANT> 
      <DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE>2</DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE> 
      <ARTICLE_NO>1599843</ARTICLE_NO> 
      <ARTICLE_NAME>Damen-T-Shirt</ARTICLE_NAME> 
      <COLOR_NO>526</COLOR_NO> 
      <COLOR>Rosa</COLOR> 
      <SIZING>42</SIZING> 
      <AMOUNT>9</AMOUNT> 
      <SUMAMOUNT>54</SUMAMOUNT> 
      <PRICE>3.45</PRICE> 
      <PRICE2>31.05</PRICE2> 
      <DISCOUNT>0</DISCOUNT> 
      <LIEFDATUM>20.07.11</LIEFDATUM> 
      <TRENNER>1599843--20.07.11</TRENNER> 
      </GROESSE_ROW>
    <GROESSE_ROW>
      <PLIEFERANT>10076002 alexa Wholesale</PLIEFERANT> 
      <DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE>2</DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE> 
      <ARTICLE_NO>1599843</ARTICLE_NO> 
      <ARTICLE_NAME>Damen-T-Shirt</ARTICLE_NAME> 
      <COLOR_NO>200</COLOR_NO> 
      <COLOR>Grün</COLOR> 
      <SIZING>42</SIZING> 
      <AMOUNT>9</AMOUNT> 
      <SUMAMOUNT>54</SUMAMOUNT> 
      <PRICE>3.45</PRICE> 
      <PRICE2>31.05</PRICE2> 
      <DISCOUNT>0</DISCOUNT> 
      <LIEFDATUM>20.07.11</LIEFDATUM> 
      <TRENNER>1599843--20.07.11</TRENNER> 
      </GROESSE_ROW>
    <GROESSE_ROW>
      <PLIEFERANT>10076002 alexa Wholesale</PLIEFERANT> 
      <DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE>2</DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE> 
      <ARTICLE_NO>1599843</ARTICLE_NO> 
      <ARTICLE_NAME>Damen-T-Shirt</ARTICLE_NAME> 
      <COLOR_NO>200</COLOR_NO> 
      <COLOR>Grün</COLOR> 
      <SIZING>44</SIZING> 
      <AMOUNT>9</AMOUNT> 
      <SUMAMOUNT>54</SUMAMOUNT> 
      <PRICE>3.45</PRICE> 
      <PRICE2>31.05</PRICE2> 
      <DISCOUNT>0</DISCOUNT> 
      <LIEFDATUM>20.07.11</LIEFDATUM> 
      <TRENNER>1599843--20.07.11</TRENNER> 
      </GROESSE_ROW>
    <GROESSE_ROW>
      <PLIEFERANT>10076002 alexa Wholesale</PLIEFERANT> 
      <DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE>2</DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE> 
      <ARTICLE_NO>1599843</ARTICLE_NO> 
      <ARTICLE_NAME>Damen-T-Shirt</ARTICLE_NAME> 
      <COLOR_NO>526</COLOR_NO> 
      <COLOR>Rosa</COLOR> 
      <SIZING>44</SIZING> 
      <AMOUNT>9</AMOUNT> 
      <SUMAMOUNT>54</SUMAMOUNT> 
      <PRICE>3.45</PRICE> 
      <PRICE2>31.05</PRICE2> 
      <DISCOUNT>0</DISCOUNT> 
      <LIEFDATUM>20.07.11</LIEFDATUM> 
      <TRENNER>1599843--20.07.11</TRENNER> 
      </GROESSE_ROW>
    <GROESSE_ROW>
      <PLIEFERANT>10076002 alexa Wholesale</PLIEFERANT> 
      <DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE>2</DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE> 
      <ARTICLE_NO>1599843</ARTICLE_NO> 
      <ARTICLE_NAME>Damen-T-Shirt</ARTICLE_NAME> 
      <COLOR_NO>200</COLOR_NO> 
      <COLOR>Grün</COLOR> 
      <SIZING>46</SIZING> 
      <AMOUNT>9</AMOUNT> 
      <SUMAMOUNT>54</SUMAMOUNT> 
      <PRICE>3.45</PRICE> 
      <PRICE2>31.05</PRICE2> 
      <DISCOUNT>0</DISCOUNT> 
      <LIEFDATUM>20.07.11</LIEFDATUM> 
      <TRENNER>1599843--20.07.11</TRENNER> 
      </GROESSE_ROW>
    <GROESSE_ROW>
      <PLIEFERANT>10076002 alexa Wholesale</PLIEFERANT> 
      <DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE>2</DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE> 
      <ARTICLE_NO>1599843</ARTICLE_NO> 
      <ARTICLE_NAME>Damen-T-Shirt</ARTICLE_NAME> 
      <COLOR_NO>526</COLOR_NO> 
      <COLOR>Rosa</COLOR> 
      <SIZING>46</SIZING> 
      <AMOUNT>9</AMOUNT> 
      <SUMAMOUNT>54</SUMAMOUNT> 
      <PRICE>3.45</PRICE> 
      <PRICE2>31.05</PRICE2> 
      <DISCOUNT>0</DISCOUNT> 
      <LIEFDATUM>20.07.11</LIEFDATUM> 
      <TRENNER>1599843--20.07.11</TRENNER> 
      </GROESSE_ROW>
    <GROESSE_ROW>
      <PLIEFERANT>10076002 alexa Wholesale</PLIEFERANT> 
      <DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE>2</DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE> 
      <ARTICLE_NO>1605278</ARTICLE_NO> 
      <ARTICLE_NAME>Herren-Jeans</ARTICLE_NAME> 
      <COLOR_NO>800</COLOR_NO> 
      <COLOR>blau</COLOR> 
      <SIZING>32/32</SIZING> 
      <AMOUNT>9</AMOUNT> 
      <SUMAMOUNT>144</SUMAMOUNT> 
      <PRICE>10.74</PRICE> 
      <PRICE2>96.66</PRICE2> 
      <DISCOUNT>0</DISCOUNT> 
      <LIEFDATUM>20.07.11</LIEFDATUM> 
      <TRENNER>1605278--20.07.11</TRENNER> 
      </GROESSE_ROW>
    <GROESSE_ROW>
      <PLIEFERANT>10076002 alexa Wholesale</PLIEFERANT> 
      <DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE>2</DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE> 
      <ARTICLE_NO>1605278</ARTICLE_NO> 
      <ARTICLE_NAME>Herren-Jeans</ARTICLE_NAME> 
      <COLOR_NO>900</COLOR_NO> 
      <COLOR>schwarz</COLOR> 
      <SIZING>32/32</SIZING> 
      <AMOUNT>9</AMOUNT> 
      <SUMAMOUNT>144</SUMAMOUNT> 
      <PRICE>10.74</PRICE> 
      <PRICE2>96.66</PRICE2> 
      <DISCOUNT>0</DISCOUNT> 
      <LIEFDATUM>20.07.11</LIEFDATUM> 
      <TRENNER>1605278--20.07.11</TRENNER> 
      </GROESSE_ROW>
    <GROESSE_ROW>
      <PLIEFERANT>10076002 alexa Wholesale</PLIEFERANT> 
      <DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE>2</DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE> 
      <ARTICLE_NO>1605278</ARTICLE_NO> 
      <ARTICLE_NAME>Herren-Jeans</ARTICLE_NAME> 
      <COLOR_NO>900</COLOR_NO> 
      <COLOR>schwarz</COLOR> 
      <SIZING>32/34</SIZING> 
      <AMOUNT>9</AMOUNT> 
      <SUMAMOUNT>144</SUMAMOUNT> 
      <PRICE>10.74</PRICE> 
      <PRICE2>96.66</PRICE2> 
      <DISCOUNT>0</DISCOUNT> 
      <LIEFDATUM>20.07.11</LIEFDATUM> 
      <TRENNER>1605278--20.07.11</TRENNER> 
      </GROESSE_ROW>
    <GROESSE_ROW>
      <PLIEFERANT>10076002 alexa Wholesale</PLIEFERANT> 
      <DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE>2</DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE> 
      <ARTICLE_NO>1605278</ARTICLE_NO> 
      <ARTICLE_NAME>Herren-Jeans</ARTICLE_NAME> 
      <COLOR_NO>800</COLOR_NO> 
      <COLOR>blau</COLOR> 
      <SIZING>32/34</SIZING> 
      <AMOUNT>9</AMOUNT> 
      <SUMAMOUNT>144</SUMAMOUNT> 
      <PRICE>10.74</PRICE> 
      <PRICE2>96.66</PRICE2> 
      <DISCOUNT>0</DISCOUNT> 
      <LIEFDATUM>20.07.11</LIEFDATUM> 
      <TRENNER>1605278--20.07.11</TRENNER> 
      </GROESSE_ROW>
    <GROESSE_ROW>
      <PLIEFERANT>10076002 alexa Wholesale</PLIEFERANT> 
      <DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE>2</DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE> 
      <ARTICLE_NO>1605278</ARTICLE_NO> 
      <ARTICLE_NAME>Herren-Jeans</ARTICLE_NAME> 
      <COLOR_NO>900</COLOR_NO> 
      <COLOR>schwarz</COLOR> 
      <SIZING>32/36</SIZING> 
      <AMOUNT>9</AMOUNT> 
      <SUMAMOUNT>144</SUMAMOUNT> 
      <PRICE>10.74</PRICE> 
      <PRICE2>96.66</PRICE2> 
      <DISCOUNT>0</DISCOUNT> 
      <LIEFDATUM>20.07.11</LIEFDATUM> 
      <TRENNER>1605278--20.07.11</TRENNER> 
      </GROESSE_ROW>
    <GROESSE_ROW>
      <PLIEFERANT>10076002 alexa Wholesale</PLIEFERANT> 
      <DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE>2</DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE> 
      <ARTICLE_NO>1605278</ARTICLE_NO> 
      <ARTICLE_NAME>Herren-Jeans</ARTICLE_NAME> 
      <COLOR_NO>800</COLOR_NO> 
      <COLOR>blau</COLOR> 
      <SIZING>32/36</SIZING> 
      <AMOUNT>9</AMOUNT> 
      <SUMAMOUNT>144</SUMAMOUNT> 
      <PRICE>10.74</PRICE> 
      <PRICE2>96.66</PRICE2> 
      <DISCOUNT>0</DISCOUNT> 
      <LIEFDATUM>20.07.11</LIEFDATUM> 
      <TRENNER>1605278--20.07.11</TRENNER> 
      </GROESSE_ROW>
    <GROESSE_ROW>
      <PLIEFERANT>10076002 alexa Wholesale</PLIEFERANT> 
      <DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE>2</DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE> 
      <ARTICLE_NO>1605278</ARTICLE_NO> 
      <ARTICLE_NAME>Herren-Jeans</ARTICLE_NAME> 
      <COLOR_NO>900</COLOR_NO> 
      <COLOR>schwarz</COLOR> 
      <SIZING>32/38</SIZING> 
      <AMOUNT>9</AMOUNT> 
      <SUMAMOUNT>144</SUMAMOUNT> 
      <PRICE>10.74</PRICE> 
      <PRICE2>96.66</PRICE2> 
      <DISCOUNT>0</DISCOUNT> 
      <LIEFDATUM>20.07.11</LIEFDATUM> 
      <TRENNER>1605278--20.07.11</TRENNER> 
      </GROESSE_ROW>
    <GROESSE_ROW>
      <PLIEFERANT>10076002 alexa Wholesale</PLIEFERANT> 
      <DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE>2</DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE> 
      <ARTICLE_NO>1605278</ARTICLE_NO> 
      <ARTICLE_NAME>Herren-Jeans</ARTICLE_NAME> 
      <COLOR_NO>800</COLOR_NO> 
      <COLOR>blau</COLOR> 
      <SIZING>32/38</SIZING> 
      <AMOUNT>9</AMOUNT> 
      <SUMAMOUNT>144</SUMAMOUNT> 
      <PRICE>10.74</PRICE> 
      <PRICE2>96.66</PRICE2> 
      <DISCOUNT>0</DISCOUNT> 
      <LIEFDATUM>20.07.11</LIEFDATUM> 
      <TRENNER>1605278--20.07.11</TRENNER> 
      </GROESSE_ROW>
    <GROESSE_ROW>
      <PLIEFERANT>10076002 alexa Wholesale</PLIEFERANT> 
      <DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE>2</DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE> 
      <ARTICLE_NO>1605278</ARTICLE_NO> 
      <ARTICLE_NAME>Herren-Jeans</ARTICLE_NAME> 
      <COLOR_NO>800</COLOR_NO> 
      <COLOR>blau</COLOR> 
      <SIZING>34/32</SIZING> 
      <AMOUNT>9</AMOUNT> 
      <SUMAMOUNT>144</SUMAMOUNT> 
      <PRICE>10.74</PRICE> 
      <PRICE2>96.66</PRICE2> 
      <DISCOUNT>0</DISCOUNT> 
      <LIEFDATUM>20.07.11</LIEFDATUM> 
      <TRENNER>1605278--20.07.11</TRENNER> 
      </GROESSE_ROW>
    <GROESSE_ROW>
      <PLIEFERANT>10076002 alexa Wholesale</PLIEFERANT> 
      <DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE>2</DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE> 
      <ARTICLE_NO>1605278</ARTICLE_NO> 
      <ARTICLE_NAME>Herren-Jeans</ARTICLE_NAME> 
      <COLOR_NO>900</COLOR_NO> 
      <COLOR>schwarz</COLOR> 
      <SIZING>34/32</SIZING> 
      <AMOUNT>9</AMOUNT> 
      <SUMAMOUNT>144</SUMAMOUNT> 
      <PRICE>10.74</PRICE> 
      <PRICE2>96.66</PRICE2> 
      <DISCOUNT>0</DISCOUNT> 
      <LIEFDATUM>20.07.11</LIEFDATUM> 
      <TRENNER>1605278--20.07.11</TRENNER> 
      </GROESSE_ROW>
    <GROESSE_ROW>
      <PLIEFERANT>10076002 alexa Wholesale</PLIEFERANT> 
      <DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE>2</DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE> 
      <ARTICLE_NO>1605278</ARTICLE_NO> 
      <ARTICLE_NAME>Herren-Jeans</ARTICLE_NAME> 
      <COLOR_NO>900</COLOR_NO> 
      <COLOR>schwarz</COLOR> 
      <SIZING>34/34</SIZING> 
      <AMOUNT>9</AMOUNT> 
      <SUMAMOUNT>144</SUMAMOUNT> 
      <PRICE>10.74</PRICE> 
      <PRICE2>96.66</PRICE2> 
      <DISCOUNT>0</DISCOUNT> 
      <LIEFDATUM>20.07.11</LIEFDATUM> 
      <TRENNER>1605278--20.07.11</TRENNER> 
      </GROESSE_ROW>
    <GROESSE_ROW>
      <PLIEFERANT>10076002 alexa Wholesale</PLIEFERANT> 
      <DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE>2</DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE> 
      <ARTICLE_NO>1605278</ARTICLE_NO> 
      <ARTICLE_NAME>Herren-Jeans</ARTICLE_NAME> 
      <COLOR_NO>800</COLOR_NO> 
      <COLOR>blau</COLOR> 
      <SIZING>34/34</SIZING> 
      <AMOUNT>9</AMOUNT> 
      <SUMAMOUNT>144</SUMAMOUNT> 
      <PRICE>10.74</PRICE> 
      <PRICE2>96.66</PRICE2> 
      <DISCOUNT>0</DISCOUNT> 
      <LIEFDATUM>20.07.11</LIEFDATUM> 
      <TRENNER>1605278--20.07.11</TRENNER> 
      </GROESSE_ROW>
    <GROESSE_ROW>
      <PLIEFERANT>10076002 alexa Wholesale</PLIEFERANT> 
      <DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE>2</DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE> 
      <ARTICLE_NO>1605278</ARTICLE_NO> 
      <ARTICLE_NAME>Herren-Jeans</ARTICLE_NAME> 
      <COLOR_NO>900</COLOR_NO> 
      <COLOR>schwarz</COLOR> 
      <SIZING>34/36</SIZING> 
      <AMOUNT>9</AMOUNT> 
      <SUMAMOUNT>144</SUMAMOUNT> 
      <PRICE>10.74</PRICE> 
      <PRICE2>96.66</PRICE2> 
      <DISCOUNT>0</DISCOUNT> 
      <LIEFDATUM>20.07.11</LIEFDATUM> 
      <TRENNER>1605278--20.07.11</TRENNER> 
      </GROESSE_ROW>
    <GROESSE_ROW>
      <PLIEFERANT>10076002 alexa Wholesale</PLIEFERANT> 
      <DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE>2</DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE> 
      <ARTICLE_NO>1605278</ARTICLE_NO> 
      <ARTICLE_NAME>Herren-Jeans</ARTICLE_NAME> 
      <COLOR_NO>800</COLOR_NO> 
      <COLOR>blau</COLOR> 
      <SIZING>34/36</SIZING> 
      <AMOUNT>9</AMOUNT> 
      <SUMAMOUNT>144</SUMAMOUNT> 
      <PRICE>10.74</PRICE> 
      <PRICE2>96.66</PRICE2> 
      <DISCOUNT>0</DISCOUNT> 
      <LIEFDATUM>20.07.11</LIEFDATUM> 
      <TRENNER>1605278--20.07.11</TRENNER> 
      </GROESSE_ROW>
    <GROESSE_ROW>
      <PLIEFERANT>10076002 alexa Wholesale</PLIEFERANT> 
      <DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE>2</DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE> 
      <ARTICLE_NO>1605278</ARTICLE_NO> 
      <ARTICLE_NAME>Herren-Jeans</ARTICLE_NAME> 
      <COLOR_NO>800</COLOR_NO> 
      <COLOR>blau</COLOR> 
      <SIZING>34/38</SIZING> 
      <AMOUNT>9</AMOUNT> 
      <SUMAMOUNT>144</SUMAMOUNT> 
      <PRICE>10.74</PRICE> 
      <PRICE2>96.66</PRICE2> 
      <DISCOUNT>0</DISCOUNT> 
      <LIEFDATUM>20.07.11</LIEFDATUM> 
      <TRENNER>1605278--20.07.11</TRENNER> 
      </GROESSE_ROW>
    <GROESSE_ROW>
      <PLIEFERANT>10076002 alexa Wholesale</PLIEFERANT> 
      <DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE>2</DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE> 
      <ARTICLE_NO>1605278</ARTICLE_NO> 
      <ARTICLE_NAME>Herren-Jeans</ARTICLE_NAME> 
      <COLOR_NO>900</COLOR_NO> 
      <COLOR>schwarz</COLOR> 
      <SIZING>34/38</SIZING> 
      <AMOUNT>9</AMOUNT> 
      <SUMAMOUNT>144</SUMAMOUNT> 
      <PRICE>10.74</PRICE> 
      <PRICE2>96.66</PRICE2> 
      <DISCOUNT>0</DISCOUNT> 
      <LIEFDATUM>20.07.11</LIEFDATUM> 
      <TRENNER>1605278--20.07.11</TRENNER> 
      </GROESSE_ROW>
    <GROESSE_ROW>
      <PLIEFERANT>10076002 alexa Wholesale</PLIEFERANT> 
      <DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE>2</DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE> 
      <ARTICLE_NO>1605278</ARTICLE_NO> 
      <ARTICLE_NAME>Herren-Jeans</ARTICLE_NAME> 
      <COLOR_NO>800</COLOR_NO> 
      <COLOR>blau</COLOR> 
      <SIZING>36/32</SIZING> 
      <AMOUNT>9</AMOUNT> 
      <SUMAMOUNT>144</SUMAMOUNT> 
      <PRICE>10.74</PRICE> 
      <PRICE2>96.66</PRICE2> 
      <DISCOUNT>0</DISCOUNT> 
      <LIEFDATUM>20.07.11</LIEFDATUM> 
      <TRENNER>1605278--20.07.11</TRENNER> 
      </GROESSE_ROW>
    <GROESSE_ROW>
      <PLIEFERANT>10076002 alexa Wholesale</PLIEFERANT> 
      <DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE>2</DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE> 
      <ARTICLE_NO>1605278</ARTICLE_NO> 
      <ARTICLE_NAME>Herren-Jeans</ARTICLE_NAME> 
      <COLOR_NO>900</COLOR_NO> 
      <COLOR>schwarz</COLOR> 
      <SIZING>36/32</SIZING> 
      <AMOUNT>9</AMOUNT> 
      <SUMAMOUNT>144</SUMAMOUNT> 
      <PRICE>10.74</PRICE> 
      <PRICE2>96.66</PRICE2> 
      <DISCOUNT>0</DISCOUNT> 
      <LIEFDATUM>20.07.11</LIEFDATUM> 
      <TRENNER>1605278--20.07.11</TRENNER> 
      </GROESSE_ROW>
    <GROESSE_ROW>
      <PLIEFERANT>10076002 alexa Wholesale</PLIEFERANT> 
      <DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE>2</DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE> 
      <ARTICLE_NO>1605278</ARTICLE_NO> 
      <ARTICLE_NAME>Herren-Jeans</ARTICLE_NAME> 
      <COLOR_NO>900</COLOR_NO> 
      <COLOR>schwarz</COLOR> 
      <SIZING>36/34</SIZING> 
      <AMOUNT>9</AMOUNT> 
      <SUMAMOUNT>144</SUMAMOUNT> 
      <PRICE>10.74</PRICE> 
      <PRICE2>96.66</PRICE2> 
      <DISCOUNT>0</DISCOUNT> 
      <LIEFDATUM>20.07.11</LIEFDATUM> 
      <TRENNER>1605278--20.07.11</TRENNER> 
      </GROESSE_ROW>
    <GROESSE_ROW>
      <PLIEFERANT>10076002 alexa Wholesale</PLIEFERANT> 
      <DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE>2</DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE> 
      <ARTICLE_NO>1605278</ARTICLE_NO> 
      <ARTICLE_NAME>Herren-Jeans</ARTICLE_NAME> 
      <COLOR_NO>800</COLOR_NO> 
      <COLOR>blau</COLOR> 
      <SIZING>36/34</SIZING> 
      <AMOUNT>9</AMOUNT> 
      <SUMAMOUNT>144</SUMAMOUNT> 
      <PRICE>10.74</PRICE> 
      <PRICE2>96.66</PRICE2> 
      <DISCOUNT>0</DISCOUNT> 
      <LIEFDATUM>20.07.11</LIEFDATUM> 
      <TRENNER>1605278--20.07.11</TRENNER> 
      </GROESSE_ROW>
    <GROESSE_ROW>
      <PLIEFERANT>10076002 alexa Wholesale</PLIEFERANT> 
      <DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE>2</DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE> 
      <ARTICLE_NO>1605278</ARTICLE_NO> 
      <ARTICLE_NAME>Herren-Jeans</ARTICLE_NAME> 
      <COLOR_NO>800</COLOR_NO> 
      <COLOR>blau</COLOR> 
      <SIZING>36/36</SIZING> 
      <AMOUNT>9</AMOUNT> 
      <SUMAMOUNT>144</SUMAMOUNT> 
      <PRICE>10.74</PRICE> 
      <PRICE2>96.66</PRICE2> 
      <DISCOUNT>0</DISCOUNT> 
      <LIEFDATUM>20.07.11</LIEFDATUM> 
      <TRENNER>1605278--20.07.11</TRENNER> 
      </GROESSE_ROW>
    <GROESSE_ROW>
      <PLIEFERANT>10076002 alexa Wholesale</PLIEFERANT> 
      <DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE>2</DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE> 
      <ARTICLE_NO>1605278</ARTICLE_NO> 
      <ARTICLE_NAME>Herren-Jeans</ARTICLE_NAME> 
      <COLOR_NO>900</COLOR_NO> 
      <COLOR>schwarz</COLOR> 
      <SIZING>36/36</SIZING> 
      <AMOUNT>9</AMOUNT> 
      <SUMAMOUNT>144</SUMAMOUNT> 
      <PRICE>10.74</PRICE> 
      <PRICE2>96.66</PRICE2> 
      <DISCOUNT>0</DISCOUNT> 
      <LIEFDATUM>20.07.11</LIEFDATUM> 
      <TRENNER>1605278--20.07.11</TRENNER> 
      </GROESSE_ROW>
    <GROESSE_ROW>
      <PLIEFERANT>10076002 alexa Wholesale</PLIEFERANT> 
      <DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE>2</DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE> 
      <ARTICLE_NO>1605278</ARTICLE_NO> 
      <ARTICLE_NAME>Herren-Jeans</ARTICLE_NAME> 
      <COLOR_NO>900</COLOR_NO> 
      <COLOR>schwarz</COLOR> 
      <SIZING>36/38</SIZING> 
      <AMOUNT>9</AMOUNT> 
      <SUMAMOUNT>144</SUMAMOUNT> 
      <PRICE>10.74</PRICE> 
      <PRICE2>96.66</PRICE2> 
      <DISCOUNT>0</DISCOUNT> 
      <LIEFDATUM>20.07.11</LIEFDATUM> 
      <TRENNER>1605278--20.07.11</TRENNER> 
      </GROESSE_ROW>
    <GROESSE_ROW>
      <PLIEFERANT>10076002 alexa Wholesale</PLIEFERANT> 
      <DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE>2</DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE> 
      <ARTICLE_NO>1605278</ARTICLE_NO> 
      <ARTICLE_NAME>Herren-Jeans</ARTICLE_NAME> 
      <COLOR_NO>800</COLOR_NO> 
      <COLOR>blau</COLOR> 
      <SIZING>36/38</SIZING> 
      <AMOUNT>9</AMOUNT> 
      <SUMAMOUNT>144</SUMAMOUNT> 
      <PRICE>10.74</PRICE> 
      <PRICE2>96.66</PRICE2> 
      <DISCOUNT>0</DISCOUNT> 
      <LIEFDATUM>20.07.11</LIEFDATUM> 
      <TRENNER>1605278--20.07.11</TRENNER> 
      </GROESSE_ROW>
    <GROESSE_ROW>
      <PLIEFERANT>10076002 alexa Wholesale</PLIEFERANT> 
      <DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE>2</DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE> 
      <ARTICLE_NO>1605278</ARTICLE_NO> 
      <ARTICLE_NAME>Herren-Jeans</ARTICLE_NAME> 
      <COLOR_NO>800</COLOR_NO> 
      <COLOR>blau</COLOR> 
      <SIZING>38/32</SIZING> 
      <AMOUNT>9</AMOUNT> 
      <SUMAMOUNT>144</SUMAMOUNT> 
      <PRICE>10.74</PRICE> 
      <PRICE2>96.66</PRICE2> 
      <DISCOUNT>0</DISCOUNT> 
      <LIEFDATUM>20.07.11</LIEFDATUM> 
      <TRENNER>1605278--20.07.11</TRENNER> 
      </GROESSE_ROW>
    <GROESSE_ROW>
      <PLIEFERANT>10076002 alexa Wholesale</PLIEFERANT> 
      <DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE>2</DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE> 
      <ARTICLE_NO>1605278</ARTICLE_NO> 
      <ARTICLE_NAME>Herren-Jeans</ARTICLE_NAME> 
      <COLOR_NO>900</COLOR_NO> 
      <COLOR>schwarz</COLOR> 
      <SIZING>38/32</SIZING> 
      <AMOUNT>9</AMOUNT> 
      <SUMAMOUNT>144</SUMAMOUNT> 
      <PRICE>10.74</PRICE> 
      <PRICE2>96.66</PRICE2> 
      <DISCOUNT>0</DISCOUNT> 
      <LIEFDATUM>20.07.11</LIEFDATUM> 
      <TRENNER>1605278--20.07.11</TRENNER> 
      </GROESSE_ROW>
    <GROESSE_ROW>
      <PLIEFERANT>10076002 alexa Wholesale</PLIEFERANT> 
      <DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE>2</DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE> 
      <ARTICLE_NO>1605278</ARTICLE_NO> 
      <ARTICLE_NAME>Herren-Jeans</ARTICLE_NAME> 
      <COLOR_NO>800</COLOR_NO> 
      <COLOR>blau</COLOR> 
      <SIZING>38/34</SIZING> 
      <AMOUNT>9</AMOUNT> 
      <SUMAMOUNT>144</SUMAMOUNT> 
      <PRICE>10.74</PRICE> 
      <PRICE2>96.66</PRICE2> 
      <DISCOUNT>0</DISCOUNT> 
      <LIEFDATUM>20.07.11</LIEFDATUM> 
      <TRENNER>1605278--20.07.11</TRENNER> 
      </GROESSE_ROW>
    <GROESSE_ROW>
      <PLIEFERANT>10076002 alexa Wholesale</PLIEFERANT> 
      <DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE>2</DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE> 
      <ARTICLE_NO>1605278</ARTICLE_NO> 
      <ARTICLE_NAME>Herren-Jeans</ARTICLE_NAME> 
      <COLOR_NO>900</COLOR_NO> 
      <COLOR>schwarz</COLOR> 
      <SIZING>38/34</SIZING> 
      <AMOUNT>9</AMOUNT> 
      <SUMAMOUNT>144</SUMAMOUNT> 
      <PRICE>10.74</PRICE> 
      <PRICE2>96.66</PRICE2> 
      <DISCOUNT>0</DISCOUNT> 
      <LIEFDATUM>20.07.11</LIEFDATUM> 
      <TRENNER>1605278--20.07.11</TRENNER> 
      </GROESSE_ROW>
    <GROESSE_ROW>
      <PLIEFERANT>10076002 alexa Wholesale</PLIEFERANT> 
      <DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE>2</DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE> 
      <ARTICLE_NO>1605278</ARTICLE_NO> 
      <ARTICLE_NAME>Herren-Jeans</ARTICLE_NAME> 
      <COLOR_NO>900</COLOR_NO> 
      <COLOR>schwarz</COLOR> 
      <SIZING>38/36</SIZING> 
      <AMOUNT>9</AMOUNT> 
      <SUMAMOUNT>144</SUMAMOUNT> 
      <PRICE>10.74</PRICE> 
      <PRICE2>96.66</PRICE2> 
      <DISCOUNT>0</DISCOUNT> 
      <LIEFDATUM>20.07.11</LIEFDATUM> 
      <TRENNER>1605278--20.07.11</TRENNER> 
      </GROESSE_ROW>
    <GROESSE_ROW>
      <PLIEFERANT>10076002 alexa Wholesale</PLIEFERANT> 
      <DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE>2</DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE> 
      <ARTICLE_NO>1605278</ARTICLE_NO> 
      <ARTICLE_NAME>Herren-Jeans</ARTICLE_NAME> 
      <COLOR_NO>800</COLOR_NO> 
      <COLOR>blau</COLOR> 
      <SIZING>38/36</SIZING> 
      <AMOUNT>9</AMOUNT> 
      <SUMAMOUNT>144</SUMAMOUNT> 
      <PRICE>10.74</PRICE> 
      <PRICE2>96.66</PRICE2> 
      <DISCOUNT>0</DISCOUNT> 
      <LIEFDATUM>20.07.11</LIEFDATUM> 
      <TRENNER>1605278--20.07.11</TRENNER> 
      </GROESSE_ROW>
    <GROESSE_ROW>
      <PLIEFERANT>10076002 alexa Wholesale</PLIEFERANT> 
      <DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE>2</DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE> 
      <ARTICLE_NO>1605278</ARTICLE_NO> 
      <ARTICLE_NAME>Herren-Jeans</ARTICLE_NAME> 
      <COLOR_NO>900</COLOR_NO> 
      <COLOR>schwarz</COLOR> 
      <SIZING>38/38</SIZING> 
      <AMOUNT>9</AMOUNT> 
      <SUMAMOUNT>144</SUMAMOUNT> 
      <PRICE>10.74</PRICE> 
      <PRICE2>96.66</PRICE2> 
      <DISCOUNT>0</DISCOUNT> 
      <LIEFDATUM>20.07.11</LIEFDATUM> 
      <TRENNER>1605278--20.07.11</TRENNER> 
      </GROESSE_ROW>
    <GROESSE_ROW>
      <PLIEFERANT>10076002 alexa Wholesale</PLIEFERANT> 
      <DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE>2</DISPATCH_TRANSPORT_TYPE> 
      <ARTICLE_NO>1605278</ARTICLE_NO> 
      <ARTICLE_NAME>Herren-Jeans</ARTICLE_NAME> 
      <COLOR_NO>800</COLOR_NO> 
      <COLOR>blau</COLOR> 
      <SIZING>38/38</SIZING> 
      <AMOUNT>9</AMOUNT> 
      <SUMAMOUNT>144</SUMAMOUNT> 
      <PRICE>10.74</PRICE> 
      <PRICE2>96.66</PRICE2> 
      <DISCOUNT>0</DISCOUNT> 
      <LIEFDATUM>20.07.11</LIEFDATUM> 
      <TRENNER>1605278--20.07.11</TRENNER> 
      </GROESSE_ROW>
</DATA>
```

This XML Structure represents an order.
And I want to create a 2-dimensional table like the table in the image.

_
(Sorry, I can't add the image with these tables. "We're sorry, but as a spam prevention mechanism, new users aren't allowed to post images. Earn more than 10 reputation to post images.")
These two tables originally are one big table that breaks across the page border. So you can see that only 4 Sizes (SIZING) fit side by side, but below one size there are 1...n Color.

The XML Structure can't be manipulated.

So I want try to add an additional tag "GROUP_ID" to every Dataset. All Datasets for the first table got the same group ID and the datasets for the second table got another ID so I can distinguish these datasets.

But it is so difficult to count or to group 4 Sizes and all Colors, because there aren't a fixed number of Sizes and no fixed number of Colors. So maybe if there are 12 Sizes, I need 3 Tables.

How can I solve this problem in XSLT?

Comment: Please, edit the question and provide the exact XML document you want to be produced as result.

Comment: I edit the XML.

It is really important for to solve this problem. If you have any questions abaut the problem. Please ask me... It is not easy to explain the correct Problem without any pictures.

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you need to have in the end. HTML?

Comment: Ah OK... A new XML Document, too.

Comment: After transformation every Rowset "GROESSE_ROW" has a "GROUP_ID"-Tag. Over this Tag I can identify in wich Table my Datset is located.

Comment: The Source of my problems is to create a Matrix Report in the BI-Publisher with tables that have to much coloums for one sheet of paper. So the table must devide in to parts or more parts.

Comment: why such a big xml? can't u provide a simpler one?
you won't get response for v. huge questions .. please keep them simple and understandable .. use a model ones.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to interpret your question, but I think you are trying to group items in a way that might be solved by the Muenchian grouping approach. The canonical description of this technique in XSLT is [Jeni Tennison's](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)
Even if you don't end up using a Muenchian, the way generate-id() is used in this approach might get your creative juices flowing.